# tccd and trustd are cycling up and down, causing severe graphics lagging every few seconds -- please help find the culprit!

Tags: macos, catalina

(cross-posted to an Apple Discussions thread, apologies)

I upgraded from High Sierra to Catalina and ever since then my computer has been super laggy. Every, say, 3-5 seconds the entire screen freezes for about a second--everything but the mouse, which keeps moving. But, for example, whatever I type gets "buffered" up and then all comes out once the freeze is done. This continues after restarts, waiting with the computer just sitting and running for over 24 hours, and closing applications.

The only thing out of the ordinary that I've found is that tccd and trustd are both cycling up and down at intervals that seem to match the occurrences of the stuttering. tccd ramps up to about 45% and trustd to about 25% CPU in Activity Monitor, then sink down to low single digits, then back up. It's creating a very distinctive sawtooth pattern in my CPU load graph.

I've spent a lot of time looking at other issues people have had with tccd in the past. I tried revoking various Accessibility permissions and other related permissions, even deleting the tcd.db User file, nothing has worked. This seems different from what most others have experienced since tccd isn't ramping up to 100% or more of CPU, trustd is involved, and this is Catalina, which I haven't seen before.

This is making my computer almost unusable! Please help!

My best guess from reading various things is that some launch daemon (?) or something is busted and keeps asking for permissions or something in the background. How can I figure out which of my extensions, apps, stupid virus checkers that various jobs have made me install, interface tools like Magnet, or something else is doing this? I tried looked at a sample of the tccd process but I didn't see anything obvious and I also don't really know how to do that or what to look for.

Thanks!

Comment: "stupid virus checkers" worries me. More than one & they are very likely to fight each other. Uninstall all [correctly - check the vendor's instructions] to test.

Comment: Fair enough! But still, there weren't any problems until I upgraded to Catalina. And I was kinda exaggerating on the stupid virus checkers--the main point is just that I've got lots of stuff/junk installed on my computer, as we all do, but I don't know where to look as far as what is causing this. Could be lots of things that are fighting each other! Thanks though. Still looking for some tips on where I can look besides just uninstalling everything on my poor computer.